# Setting Up TFS Server outside of a domain

Tags: sql-server, tfs

Im trying to set up TFS 2010 on a machine that is connected to a network, but not on the domain.
I am trying to connect this to a SQL Server that is also connected to the network and also not on the domain. When I run through the TFS configuration Wizard and try to connect to the SQL Server, it fails with a message "A connection can not be made...." which looks like it cant see the Server. However when i connect through SQL Management Studio it works when i use SQL Authentication (not Windows Auth). I beleive its failing because TFS needs to connect using Windows Authetication (please correct me if im wrong). I can not add the Windows Authentication for my TFS machine onto the SQL machine becuase they are on different domains (again, pleas correct me if I'm wrong).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible but have you tried duplicate local users for both TFS and SQL Server's Windows Authentication? I'm not entirely sure if this works or is even possible, but this may give you a setup where Windows Authentication is still used but without a domain. The main problem with this is that it's a maintenance PITA since you have to independently keep the two (or more) accounts in sync with each other (meaning username and passwords).

It's just a thought if adding the servers to a domain is completely impossible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666945/is-active-directory-required-for-a-team-using-tfs-2010 is a similar question where this same thing has been proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to enrol the server(s) onto the domain? Is there a reason they aren't already? It may be because TFS is trying to a use a named pipes connection rather than TCP which may be the cause

Comment: Cheers @Rowland, I'll give it a go. Im fairly new to this TFS set up stuff, at my old place of work, some other unlucky fool set it up.

Comment: @Ben It's a function I'd normally associate with an Infrastructure department, so you might get better answers on ServerFault, too

Comment: Life gets so bad in so many ways so quickly if you're running without a domain.  Of course, if you are so small that you don't even have a domain set up, chances are TFS isn't exactly the right product for you in the first place! :)

Comment: @Dave he did say "not on **the** domain" rather than "we don't have a domain", luckily

Comment: He had me scared there for a second :)